# No matches found or No matches were found

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I'd like to know which of this two expression is grammatically correct to show in a message in a website, when the users filter and there's no data returned from the server.

Comment: Both seem correct to me, the difference is in the tense

Comment: "No matches found" is an elided version of either "There were no matches found" or "No matches were found".  It's not strictly "correct" in terms of syntax, as it isn't a complete sentence, but it is considered acceptable in all but the most formal registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference I can think of (though both variants are indeed correct, as has already been commented) is related to whether your message appears *during* or *after*, say, the search.

"No answers were found" is quite explicit as to what is meant:

A search was done, but it yielded no results.

"No answers found", on the other hand, loose as it is, may connote that the search didn't yield and is *still* not yielding any results, so it may be more suitable in case the message appears in real-time, while the search is still being executed.